# touch up inside not working on xcode 6

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm working on a 2 view game, something simple, which was originally built using xcode5, I have just updated to xcode6 and now the "touch-up-inside" to drop some tiles has just stopped working.

I have double check all my code, and notes and nothing has changed, other than xcode itself!

I know xcode6 hasn't long been out, so i was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how to solve this problem?